# Firebase doesn't update the query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have this code for retrieve my data from database and show it in my recyclerview, but I have no idea how update the query to make an endless list of my data. I search in many posts but I'm new on android and firebase and it's complicated for me.

The toast in the scrolllistener only shows the first time(the code works in that part) but the others not, because the int page change his value, and the recyclerview doesn't show the other elements.
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

```
public class FragmentPrincipal extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference dReference, mReference;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GuardarReview, ReviewViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
private int itemsPerPage = 6, page = 1;
private int visibleItemCount;
private boolean loading;
private Query query;

public FragmentPrincipal(){

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    dReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mReference = dReference.child("Reviews");

    query = mReference.orderByChild("date").limitToFirst(page * itemsPerPage);

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GuardarReview, ReviewViewHolder>
            (GuardarReview.class, R.layout.columna_reviews, ReviewViewHolder.class, query ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ReviewViewHolder viewHolder, GuardarReview model, int position) {

            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.titulo);
            viewHolder.setImage(getContext(), model.imagenURL);

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerReview.class);
                    intent.putExtra("review_id", post_key);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy >= 0) {

                if(!loading){

                    visibleItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getChildCount();

                    if(visibleItemCount >= (page * itemsPerPage)){

                        page++;
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fin de la lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading = true;

                        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
                loading = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflador, ViewGroup contenedor, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View vista = inflador.inflate(R.layout.inicio_fragment, contenedor, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return vista;
}

public static class ReviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public ReviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){

        TextView review_titulo = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.review_titulo);
        review_titulo.setText(title);

    }

    public void setImage(Context context, String imagenURL){

        ImageView review_imagen = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.review_imagen);
        Picasso.with(context).load(imagenURL).placeholder(R.drawable.loading3).into(review_imagen);

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.cleanup();
}
}
```